# Where are my files - Ubuntu 14 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, files

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12 to 14. Ubuntu 14 upgrade program asked me for new account name and password I entered the same account name as it was in Ubuntu 12. Upgrade was successfully finished but there are not my files in my home folder anymore, it is totally empty. Is there any way I can retrieve my files.

Comment: An upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 should never ask for a username and password. I did this upgrade on several machines and never seen such a dialog. Sure you did an upgrade? What steps did you do? Was there any install medium involved?

Comment: Maybe I did install with keep old files options, I do not remember well. I know it should preserve my old files.

Comment: I did upgrade - install from live USB.

Comment: Could you do `ls -l /home` ? It probably shows a directory for your old user, and one for the newly created one

Comment: It shows 2 folders, one has name as current user name the other is old one with the same name as my older one with missing files but both are empty